# PDF/DOC/XLS Documents won't open after deploying vb.net web app

Tags: vb.net, deployment

I am relatively new to vb.net, so please bear with me. . .

I created a web app using Visual Studio Professional 2012.  When I was coding/testing on my box, everything worked well.  Now that I have deployed the project to our server, I am having a problem.  While in my application, the user clicks a hyperlink (filename) and I use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(PDFFile) to open my documents.  Before deployment, it would open pdf/doc/xls documents, but after deployment, I receive the following error message:

The system cannot find the drive specified

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the drive specified

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the drive specified]
   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +1075
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +60
   CEI_PerformanceReviews.ScannedReviewReader.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +301
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

I've tried to rename some of the filenames to see if it didn't like the Network Mapping.  That got rid of the error message.  I don't really understand the above stack trace - was it telling me that it didn't like the mapping?

After changing the filename, the error seems to have gone away, but now nothing happens.    It doesn't appear to be trying to open the document I click on.  I've checked on the server that I have deployed to, and it doesn't have Microsoft office installed.  Could that be the problem?  Again, I'm new to this, so please excuse my lack of understanding.

If anyone could please help me resolve this problem, I would appreciate the help.

Thank you!

Wendy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace was telling you that it did not understand the path you were providing to the `StartWithShellExecute` method.

Yes, the issue is most likely that you do not have any software on the server that can handle the PDF/DOC/XLS MIME types.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I was afraid that might be the problem.  Are there any options - other than installing Windows Office on the server?  Is there something in Visual Studio 2012 that I could use as an alternative?

Comment: Does the file need to be opened on the server? In other words, could you stream the file to the client instead? If you can stream the file to the client, then the necessity for Office (Word, Excel, etc.) or Adobe Reader (PDF) is on the client's machine and not the server anymore.

Comment: I think I can.  My rookie assumption was that is how it would open  anyway.  I'm just not sure the correct way to code for it.  I'm researching asp.net hyperlinks to better understand what my options are.

Comment: You might want to also research ASP.NET HttpHandlers, as you can easily build up server-side logic to send files to the client, even if they are just regular HTML anchor tags via jQuery's `.ajax()` method.

Comment: Thank you Karl.  It sounds a bit over my head, but I will research HttpHandlers, too.  Wish me luck :)

Comment: @Wendy - Don't be intimidated, there are lots of great tutorials out there for all things .NET. You are motivated enough to ask questions on here so you are ahead of the curve from most developers I have worked with.